# Invalid delivery method error when trying to use a custom DeliveryMethod in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, mail-gem

I've built a custom email delivery method for my Rails 4 app:

```
module CustomDeliverer
  class DeliveryMethod

    def initialize(options = {})
    end

    def deliver!(mail)
      # method body hidden/not relevant for this question
    end
  end
end
```

I've also followed [the example in the letter opener gem](https://github.com/ryanb/letter_opener/blob/master/lib/letter_opener/railtie.rb) to register a custom delivery method:

```
module CustomDeliverer
  class Railtie < Rails::Railtie
    initializer "custom_deliverer.add_delivery_method" do
      ActiveSupport.on_load :action_mailer do
        ActionMailer::Base.add_delivery_method :custom_deliverer, CustomDeliverer::DeliveryMethod
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I've set my config file to use this deliverer:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :custom_deliverer
```

When I try to deliver a mail in my app, I get the error:

> Invalid delivery method :custom_deliverer

However, when I set the config file to use the deliverer directly:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = CustomDeliverer::DeliveryMethod
```

it works correctly, but anytime that code changes in the application (when developing locally), I get the error:

> CustomDeliverer::DeliveryMethod has been removed from the module tree
>   but is still active!

Where am I supposed to register or require CustomDeliverer::Railtie in my rails app so that I can set the delivery method via a symbol?

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out:

Instead of using a Railtie, which is just meant for gems, added an initializer, config/initializers/add_custom_delivery_method.rb:

```
ActiveSupport.on_load :action_mailer do
  ActionMailer::Base.add_delivery_method :custom_deliverer, CustomDeliverer::DeliveryMethod
end
```